Not able to call GET API with Date request param in Spring boot project
I am trying to call a GET API with LocalDateTime format but it keeps giving error that the request param is missing.
Here is the API I am trying to call
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.GET) public void apiCall(@RequestParam("restrictProfileDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime restrictProfileDate) {
And here is the code that I am using to call this API
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();   
    LocalDate deltascreeningDate = LocalDate.now();
    Date date = Date.from(dateValue.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()); 

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("restrictProfileDate", formattedDate);
    
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(apiEndPoint, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(params, headers), String.class);

The error I am getting is "WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required LocalDateTime parameter 'restrictProfileDate' is not present]"

Can you call the endpoint from the browser, console or postman?

Yes, I am able to successfully call the endpoint from postman. Param passed "restrictProfileDate":"2024-04-26 00:00:00"

If the error message is to be believed, then you just need params.put("restrictProfileDate", deltascreeningDate.atStartOfDay());. Or perhaps params.put("restrictProfileDate", LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())); if time of day is to be included

Also you should have stayed off the troublesome and outdated Date and SimpleDateFormat classes anyway. So the message is helpful in that respect too.

new HttpEntity<>(params, headers)

Actually uses first argument as a body, not as query params.
You should pass params after String.class like this
restTemplate.exchange(apiEndPoint, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(params, headers), String.class, params)

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity,java.lang.Class,java.util.Map)
